# What to do if not jumuah 3x (or more) in a row

Tags: salat, jumuah

I just did it because i lazy and now i regret it. I heard that it means i'm kafir now because i didn't jumuah 3x in a row , what i should do now to go back to islam ?

I also heard that not jumuah 3x in a row will result my heart get locked by God , is there anything i can do to unlock my heart ? or it is locked forever now ?

I already tried searching on internet but cant find what to do.

Comment: Just repent and start praying jummah.

Comment: is that it ? just that ?

Comment: What else do you expect?

Comment: so if i repent and start praying jumuah again , will the seal from my heart unlocked ?

Comment: Sure, if Allah wills.

Comment: oh okay then , thank

Answer (score -1):

You are not a kadir but there is a hadith about seal even tho I don't remember who said it:

"Whoever missed three jumu’ahs out of negligence, Allah (SWT) will place a seal over his heart.”

Comment: yea i know , and is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: all i can find on internet is to not to not jumuah 3x in a row , but i cant find anything what to do after not jumuah 3x in a row

Comment: see this article: https://blog.islamiconlineuniversity.com/9-ways-to-purify-your-heart-with-the-remembrance-of-allah/